# How retrain inceptionV3?

Tags: java, tensorflow

I try retrain inception !!
When the last train script and library version is used my code gives error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
  GraphDef  at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Native Method)   at  
  org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:130)
```

For train model I am using a common script  with these flags:

```
python D://retrain.py --image_dir D:\train
```

Problem string:

```
Tensor result =  s.runner().feed("DecodeJpeg/contents",image).fetch("softmax").run().get(0)) ;
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid GraphDef at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Native Method) at
org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:130)
```

All code is [here](https://pastebin.com/sfVGSxUb)

Comment: Please post properly formatted code. Put four spaces in front of the code lines in your post, so that StackOverflow will show it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How train  inceptionV3 for this code**

1. In  code change:

   ```
   Tensor result =  s.runner().feed("DecodeJpeg/contents",image).fetch("softmax").run().get(0))
   ```

to

```
Tensor result = s.runner().feed("DecodeJpeg/contents", image).fetch("final_result").run().get(0))
```

2. Download Tensorflw native libs from here : [Here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/tensorflow/libtensorflow_jni/1.6.0/libtensorflow_jni-1.6.0.jar)
3. Third step is unpack .jar like .zip and copy lib file in your project folder.
4. Just  get retrain.py from : [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py)
5. Open command prompt and enter command :

   ```
   python (path to retrain.py)  --image_dir (path to image) -- output_graph (path to graph files(.pb) -- output_labels(path to label(.txt)
   ```
6. Find .pb file rename it to label.pb and use in code
7. Enjoy coding